# Problem with Scala StructType for streaming in Databricks

Tags: scala, parquet

I am battling with a datatype and wondered if someone could assist me. I am doing a structured stream using Event Grid, Azure Databricks into Azure Synapse. The file in question is parquet format and I am using scala.

When I do a printschema on the file, there are two columns that come up as decimal (`6,2`) one of which is causing an issue. The column that is giving issues has null values, the other decimal column has integer values.

I create StructType and for these two fields, I use the type DoubleType for the two decimal fileds.  When I do this, I get the following error message for the decimal column that contains nulls

```
Error while reading file wasbs:REDACTED_LOCAL_PART@storage.blob.core.windows.net/part-00000-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxx-xxx.c000.snappy.parquet. Parquet column cannot be converted. Column: [FlUsed], Expected: DoubleType, Found: INT32
```

Then when if I change the structure to an IntegerType as suggested in the error message, and run the stream I get the following error message.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainIntegerDictionary
```

If I convert the parquet to csv first then everything works perfectly but this is not a long term solution.  From what I have read, this is clearly an issue with the datatype but I don't know what to do to solve it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly the solution without seeing some example code, however you may need to cast the column. You can do this using something like the following:

```
col("myColumn").cast(DoubleType)
```

I'd guess from what you have said you should be setting the input type either to DecimalType(6,2), or IntegerType. The output type is probably DoubleType.

Comment: Hi Nick,   Thank you, I will try that .. I don't mind sharing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I will try to cast it, ... posting code here as comments does not allow enough characters.

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(
   StructField("field1 ", StringType),
   StructField("field2 ", TimestampType),
   StructField("field5", StringType),                       
   StructField("field6", IntegerType), // spark.read and schema show reads the schema as follows decimal(6,2) – field actually contains integers 
   StructField("field7", IntegerType), // spark.read and schema show reads the schema as follows decimal(6,2) – field actually contains nulls .. this is the one giving the problem .. explicitly setting null ability value to true doesn't help
   StructField("field8", StringType), 
   StructField("field14", IntegerType)
))

 val stream = spark.readStream
   .format("abs-aqs")
   .option("fileFormat", "parquet")
   .option("queueName", "inbound-events")
   .option("connectionString", s"xxx")
   .schema(schema)
   .load()
```

Comment: Put this into your original question 